# Should the "ecb" tag be split into "ecb" and "emacs-ecb"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Most of the [questions tagged "ecb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecb) are related to Electronic Codebook mode, which is also the subject of the tag wiki. However, there are are fair number of questions with the same tag which are on the (completely unrelated) subject of Emacs ECB (Emacs Code Browser).

Should the Emacs ECB questions be retagged "emacs-ecb"? Also, should the "ecb" tag be renamed to something more specific, such as "electronic-codebook", or left as "ecb"?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best to keep the existing tag (to avoid confusion), and for the Emacs Code Browser, use one of the following tags:

## [emacs-ecb](/questions/tagged/emacs-ecb)
[emacs-code-browser](/questions/tagged/emacs-code-browser)
[emacs-cb](/questions/tagged/emacs-cb)
[ecb-emacs](/questions/tagged/ecb-emacs)